# how to add a local box file into vagrant box

Tags: vagrant

I'm learning vagrant( https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/getting-started/boxes.html ) ,because I can't directly "vagrant box add hashicorp/precise64" as is written on the page, first I downloaded hashicorp/precise64, then added it. It said "box:successfully added box 'hashicorp/premise64'(v0) for virtualbox". Then I configured vagrantfile as is written on the page.But when I "vagrant up",it said"Box  'hashicorp/premise64'  could not be found'. ..... Process 0%......".I've been searching a solution, but can't find.Can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: To clarify did you run `vagrant box add hashicorp/precise64`?

Answer (score 0):

Awesome to see you trying out Vagrant as it is a very useful tool. Some background on hashicorp/precise64, this box is popular yes, but is a dated version of Ubuntu 12.04. I would recommend using ubuntu/xenial64 which is Ubuntu 16.04. To use this you will first run:

`vagrant init ubuntu/xenial64`

then

`vagrant up`

This process may take some time as it is initializing the box for the first time. Once it is up and running feel free to ssh into it:

`vagrant ssh`

I also recommend taking a look at their quick start guide [here](https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/getting-started/install.html).

Comment: Thanks. I did run  "vagrant box add hashicorp/precise64,but it always failed. So I downloaded the box file first, and added it. And it said "added successfully ", But when I run 'vagrant up ', it said " the box could not be found ".